# d3.js onmousehover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I wrote this code using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/).

Here's my problem:

When you mouse over the rectangles, the pop up tooltip appears, but not when the pointer is over the text within the rectangle.

I would like the tooltip to appear when the mouse is over the text as well as the other parts of the shape. How can this be accomplished?

Here's my code for the rectangle:

```
cartridgeRectangles.push({"x_axis":startx+2, "y_axis":90+textbeginy, "width":35,       "height":15, "color":discovery_status_color, "stroke":"#33CC33", "thickness":1, "mover":chassisDetails , "movercolor":"darkgreen", "mout":"True", "moutcolor":"#33CC33" });
```

Comment: Consider asking about the gif image in a new post. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the text is capturing the mouse. This can be avoided by removing the pointer events for the text in css:

```
// This will apply to all text elements, consider using a class
text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

More information in pointer events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Thank You, You solved my one problem  but can You also help with image problem?

Comment: That is the problem with multiple questions in one post. Please, edit this post and create a new post for the image issue. I will be glad to help if I can.